# "Error: Capture" while returning URL from Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, google-search

I'm using this snippet to make Google search starting to a given name:

```
var parseXlsx = require('excel');
var scraper = require('google-search-scraper');

parseXlsx('foo.xlsx', function(err, data) {
  if(err) throw err;
    // data is an array of arrays
    for(var i=1; i<5; i++){
        var stringToSearch = data[i][0];
        var options = {
            query: stringToSearch,
            limit: 1
        };
        scraper.search(options, function(err, url) {
            // This is called for each result
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(url)
        });
    }
});
```

In `foo.xlsx` file I have this column:

```
name1
name2
name3
....
```

I'm getting always this error, and I don't know why:

```
Error: Captcha
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\user\node_modules\google-search-scraper\index.js:68:23)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\user\node_modules\google-search-scraper\node_modules\request\request.js:122:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\node_modules\google-search-scraper\node_modules\request\request.js:888:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at Request.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\node_modules\google-search-scraper\node_modules\request\request.js:839:12)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
```

Comment: works for me with node.js 7.0.0, google-search-scraper: 0.0.3, excel: 0.1.7. maybe you just have to update them.

Comment: i have node js 7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sounds like it can't get passed a RECAPCHA.

> Error:Capcha

Have you tried using  **deathbycaptcha** - npm package to solve ?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deathbycaptcha

```
var scraper = require('google-search-scraper');
var DeathByCaptcha = require('deathbycaptcha');

var dbc = new DeathByCaptcha('username', 'password');

var options = {
  query: 'site:edu "information theory"',
  age: 'y', // less than a year,
  solver: dbc
};

scraper.search(options, function(err, url) {
  // This is called for each result
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(url)
});
```

Comment: where i can get username and password?

Comment: it's a payment solution, not worth